# How to display iframe based on JS output

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to display an `iframe` in my website if a user accepts an alert box message to see the website.

For example, if a user clicks on the career page, I'll show him an alert box by giving two options ( if he selected "yes" ). I have to display my webpage as an `iframe` in the same page.

I tried the following by writing the function in JS

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
  if (r==true) {
    <iframe src="http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp" width="100%" height="100%">
    </iframe>
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where are you creating your new iframe?

Comment: @KawineshSK HTML page

Comment: If you are not trying to access a protected resource have a 'dislapy:none' to that iframe when your page gets loaded and just change the 'css to display:block' using 'jquery' whenever you wish.

Comment: @Pavi, you will not be properly serving your users if you use the `display:none` way. The way I showed you makes **sure** the page is only loaded if the visitor *decides* to open it, and not beforehand. The `display: none` way makes people angry, and it costs you server resources whether or not someone chooses to participate!

Comment: i have to display three different iframes for three different buttons. do i have to write same no of blocks in css

Comment: Now that you have the technique sorted out, this seems like a time for a new question with fresh code to answer again, linked to this one. Can you do that so you don't disturb your first question? It's very clear and self contained.

Comment: I added a second answer to my first answer. Your second question was much larger than the first, but I simplified it for you and included code. I hope this helps you understand javascript and the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? If so, check this out! I show you two ways to place the `iframe`:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var r=confirm("Press a button!");
   if (r==true) {

       //de put it at the end of the body
       $( '<iframe src="http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp" width="100%" height="100%"</iframe>' ).appendTo( "body" );

       //de put it in a pre-decided container.
       $( '<iframe src="http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp" width="100%" height="100%"</iframe>' ).appendTo( "#container" );

   }
}
</script>
```

This is a much better way than just "revealing it" because you seem to WANT the user to *choose* to bring up the `iframe`... The way above is very close to what you originally tried to do. You just needed to actually insert the element into the `DOM` as I showed.

Good luck!

**UPDATE:** I also answered your much larger question ... here is a completely cleaned and working version of what you needed with seperate `iframes`:

http://jsfiddle.net/W2e6u

It goes like this, with the HTML in the fiddle for you to look at:

```
function changeContainer(uri) {
    var r=confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r==true) {
        $( '#container' ).fadeOut('fast').remove();
        $( '<iframe id="container" src="http://www.nabler.com/services/'+uri+'.asp" width="100%" height="100%"</iframe>' ).appendTo( "body" );
    }
}
```

And an HTML button example:

```
<button onclick="changeContainer('campaign-analytics')">Campaign Analytics and Reporting</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. i used ur code and it works as i expected. However i am facing the problem while clicking on other buttons. Iframe which downloaded for the first time while i clicked on some button is not changing even when i was clicking on other buttons

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked for you. Do you have a fiddle or example site showing this in use? I can help tweak it further. What does your new code look like?

Comment: i posted it on my blog for checking purpose.. kindly have a look http://techshale.blogspot.in/ in the testing page

Comment: Great! First of all, you don't need both `appendTo` lines. I just gave two examples. You can choose whether you want the `iframe` inserted into the `<body>` element, or into a new `#container` element.

Comment: I answered your question again, with a lot of detail and a js fiddle. Everything is in my answer above, as an update.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to append the iframe to the DOM when YES clicked.

```
    function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

var fragment = create('<div>Hello!</div><p>...</p>');
// You can use native DOM methods to insert the fragment:
document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: If you aren't using jQuery, this is a great answer. Props to @Yagiz for using native methods in case.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/sEz8C/

**JS:-**

```
function myFunction() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");

    if (r == true) {
        var myDiv=document.getElementById("test");
        var makeIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        makeIframe.setAttribute("src", "http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp");
        makeIframe.style.width = "100%";
        makeIframe.style.height = "100%";
        myDiv.appendChild(makeIframe);
    }
}
myFunction();
```